# Is there a action/filter hook to check if the user's account is verified in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, user-input

I've created a simple algorithm to add a user to our site's API after it registers his or her info.

```
function send_reg_userdata_to_api($user_id) {
    $reg_data = get_userdata($user_id);

    //check if $_POST['pass1'] exist, set $_POST['pass1'] to password, else set it to ******** (default password for social login)
    if (isset($_POST['pass1'])) {
        $password = $_POST['pass1'];
    } else {
        $password = '********';
    }

    $user_data = array(
        'user_name' => $reg_data->display_name,
        'password' => $password
    );

    //**PROBLEM**
    //Want to trigger this apply_filters() when user's account will verified
    //apply_filters('wp_my_api', 'post', $user_data);
    //instead I store it to a variable to pass its data when a HOOK that i needed will triggered        
    $reg_user_data = $user_data;
}
add_action('user_register', 'send_reg_userdata_to_api');
```

I checked all at the WordPress Codex and also here about the solution about the problem but still have no luck on it. I'm using Theme My Login for register, login and verifying user's info and Social Socializer to connect users to the site using social accounts.

Any help, ideas and suggestions is heavenly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.